# How do I translate Ruby's IO.popen calls into Python's subprocess.Popen calls?

Tags: python, ruby, subprocess, popen, io

I've read the documentation and I've tried lots of things in the REPL, and Googled, but I can't for the life of me understand how [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).Popen works in Python.

Here is some Ruby code I am using:

```
IO.popen("some-process") do |io|
  while(line = io.gets)
    # do whatever with line
  end
end
```

How do I translate this into Python using subprocess.Popen?

Comment: There are many useful examples of how to use `subprocess` here: http://blog.doughellmann.com/2007/07/pymotw-subprocess.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest "close relative" of your Ruby code in Python:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> io = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
>>> for line in io: print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Note that reading from a `Popen`'s `stdout` carries some risk of deadlocks. It's generally preferred to use `communicate` if blocking is acceptable.

Comment: @Mike, if the subprocess just closes its stdin first thing (as `ls` does -- as `some-process` had better do in the Ruby code since it's **never** given **any** input!) no deadlock is possible in any OS I know of.  Only subprocesses that **use** their stdin are at any conceivable risk -- so your "generally" is just totally inapplicable to both this Q and my A.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['ls',], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.communicate()[0]
```